# How do I get avr-gdb to automatically connect to a remote target on startup?

Tags: gdb

If I want to connect to the target with `avr-gdb` (I think it would be the same with standard `gdb`) I usually do:

```
avr-gdb <executable_file> 
target remote localhost:<port>
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
avr-gdb -<option> target remote localhost:<port> <executable_file>
```

I have tried

```
avr-gdb -ex target remote localhost:<port> <executable_file>
```

but it seems to split up the commands

Answer (score 2):

I found that all I had to do was surround the command with quotes, so:

```
avr-gdb -ex 'target remote localhost:<port>' <executable_file>
```